# jenkins pipeline with docker registry credential error

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-registry, dtr

I am getting error while trying to login dtr from my pipeline groovy scrit. it is saying that that was a credential error.

```
docker.withRegistry('https://dtrlb-oe3ko7eumonjw.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/','ddcadmin')
```

and my error is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDzw6.png)

Answer (score 0):

The docker.withRegistry can find credential in Global domain, not system domain.